# select count with another select and inner join

Tags: mysql, sql

Is it possible to use two "select" in the same query?

I tried it but got the syntax error several times.

My query example:

```
            SELECT 
                comp.id, 
                comp.document, 
                comp.dateStart, 
                comp.companyName, 
                comp.fantasyName, 
                comp.legalNature, 
                comp.mainActivity, 
                comp.situation, 
                comp.shareCapital, 
                comp.idCompanyStatus,
                pp.userCredentialId,
                uc.name,
                cs.name AS 'nameStatus',
                cs.color AS 'colorStatus',
                cs.description,
                comp.idPurchasedProduct, 
                comp.actived, 
                comp.createAt, 
                comp.updateAt,
                comp.phone
            FROM `PurchasedProduct` pp 
            INNER JOIN 
                `Company` comp on comp.idPurchasedProduct = pp.id
            INNER JOIN 
                `UserCustomer` uc on pp.userCredentialId = uc.credentialId
            INNER JOIN
                `CompanyStatus` cs on cs.id = comp.idCompanyStatus
            WHERE 
                comp.actived = 1
            LIMIT 0,5;          
        SELECT COUNT(id) AS totalItems, CEILING(COUNT(id) / 10) AS totalPages FROM Company;
```

I would like the result shown to be all queries on the screen.

Basically, what I want is that the result shown when executing the query is the first and second "select" together.
I really don't know how or don't understand how to do this.

Example:

[first result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cVUOA.png) with [seconde result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vnyzJ.png)

I want to show both results at once.

**The documents is fake, not real. Only for demo.**

Comment: Maybe using `UNION ALL`? Both queries need to have the same number of columns, though. You could do: `SELECT ... UNION ALL SELECT ...`.

Comment: Please note that `LIMIT`ing without `ORDER`ing rarely makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do by having the second query as its own JOIN query.  Since there is no group by, it is only returning a single row.  By no join condition, the value will be available for every row otherwise.  So you SHOULD be able to get by doing

```
select
      [ all your other columns ],
      JustCounts.TotalItems,
      JustCounts.TotalPages
   from
      [PurchasedProduct and all your other joins]
         JOIN ( SELECT 
                      COUNT(id) AS totalItems, 
                      CEILING(COUNT(id) / 10) AS totalPages 
                   FROM Company ) as JustCounts
   where
      [rest of your original query]
```